# format Data in stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

After a little bit of advise.

We are producing a standard list of data with filters.

This filtered list can have 3 alternative views which represent the data in different manor
my question is:

- should the stored procedure return the data in the format that is required for each view for the front end?
- or should the business layer re-format the data?

I have always believed it best to get in and out of the database as fast as possible, and allow the business layer to handle formatting.

Thanks in advance for any advise

UPDATE:-
by formating,

1 view contain all data withing a scrollable table

2 view will group data withing headings, (click on a heading to expand to view)

3 view will group data into date groups and display dates as table row headers (7 day intivials) and the data count will be displayed within those intivals

Comment: Your business layer should be used for presentation and formatting, no doubt. The database processes the data as much as possible, and your reporting tool handle presentation.  You can, with all sorts of effort, do some presentation type manipulation in your SQL, but it's not worth it.

Comment: @ChrisBint question updated, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have always believed it best to get in and out of the database as
>   fast as possible, and allow the business layer to handle formatting.

Short answer: Correct, you have answered your own question.

The database returns *data* to your application, how it is presented is up to the application. What happens when you want to supply the same data to another application? Do you want to have to write procedures every time you want the data in a different format? Of course not.

> 1: view contain all data withing a scrollable table

You cannot return a scrolling window from a procedure. Anyway, how would the database know how much data will need to be scrolled? It does not know the size of window/viewport you are using.

> 2: view will group data withing headings, (click on a heading to expand to view)

This requires user interaction which is solely the domain of the presentation layer.

> 3: view will group data into date groups and display dates as table
>   row headers (7 day intivials) and the data count will be displayed
>   within those intivals

You can return multiple result sets from a procedure, to give the results and the counts, but again this is more easily handled in the application.

Answer (score 0):

In general you should use the presentation layer to format your data output.  You can have the stored procedure return the raw data set and then set up, for example 3 different XSLT files for the 3 different presentation types.  This way you can always do DataTable.ToXML and apply the XSLT template to this output to produce the format that the user needs.